Multiple ResponsiveGridLayout which is connected to each other in the react-grid-layout package with ReactJS
I want to create a A4 size page and user can add block from outside of the page, user can move block within the page and also, user can move block from one page to another page.
Also user can add multiple page and the functionally should work for all pages.
For this, I was creating a ResponsiveGridLayout for each A4 size page.
Draging block from outside and moving block within page was working fine but When I move block from one page to another page, is not working.
I was using react-grid-layout package. Here is the code for reference:
// App.js

function generateLayout() {
  return _.map(_.range(0, 15), function (item, i) {
    var y = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    return {
      x: Math.round(Math.random() * 5) * 2,
      y: Math.floor(i / 6) * y,
      w: 2,
      h: y,
      i: i.toString(),
      static: Math.random() < 0.05,
    };
  });
}

const App = () => {
  const [pages, setPages] = useState({ 1: generateLayout() });

  const handleAddPage = () => {
    const newPageNumber = Object.keys(pages).length + 1;
    setPages({
      ...pages,
      [newPageNumber]: generateLayout(),
    });
  };

  const handleBlockDrop = (pageNumber, layout, item) => {
    console.log({ layout }, { item });
    item.i = String(layout.length);
    setPages((prevPages) => ({
      ...prevPages,
      [pageNumber]: layout,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAddPage}>Add Page</button>
      <div
        className="droppable-element"
        draggable={true}
        unselectable="on"
        onDragStart={(e) => e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", "")}
      >
        Droppable Element (Drag me!)
      </div>
      {Object.keys(pages).map((pageNumber) => (
        <>
          <h2>Page {pageNumber}</h2>
          <A4Page
            key={pageNumber}
            page={pageNumber}
            blocks={pages[pageNumber]}
            onBlockDrop={handleBlockDrop}
          />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

//A4Page.js

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(Responsive);

const A4Page = ({ page, blocks, onBlockDrop }) => {
  console.log({ page, blocks });
  const styles = {
    width: "8.27in",
    height: "11.69in",
    border: "1px solid #ddd",
    padding: "10px",
    margin: "10px",
    display: "flex",
  };

  const onLayoutChange = (newLayout) => {
    console.log("Layout changed", newLayout);
  };

  const onDrop = (layout, item) => {
    console.log("on drop functino called");
    onBlockDrop(page, layout, item);
  };

  const onDragStop = (layout, item) => {
    console.log("on drag stop function called", layout, item);
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles} key={page}>
      <ResponsiveGridLayout
        className="layout"
        style={{ height: "11.69in", width: "100%" }}
        compactType={null}
        preventCollision={!null}
        isDroppable={true}
        isDraggable={true}
        onDrop={onDrop}
        onDragStop={onDragStop}
        onLayoutChange={onLayoutChange}
        layouts={{
          lg: blocks,
          md: blocks,
          sm: blocks,
          xs: blocks,
          xxs: blocks,
        }}
        cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
        rowHeight={40}
        maxRows={22}
      >
        {blocks.map((block) => (
          <div key={block.i}>
            {block.i} := {block.x + ", " + block.y}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ResponsiveGridLayout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default A4Page;


I have tried multople thigs but none of them working as I wanted to be.
I want, user can move block from one page to another page.
